# QGIS Graphical Modeler Help editor does not save

Tags: qgis, text, qgis-modeler

Is there a special way to save whatever text you're writing in the Help Editor for a QGIS Model? I've been trying a few times, apparently just after I click ok, even though I immediately click "save" afterwards, the description gets deleted.

Any ideas on what's happening?

**Using QGIS 2.8.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

Found out what the problem was but not in the technical sense. Apparently, if you upgrade the Processing Plugin to version 2.9.3, latest one, you won't have any issues with it anymore.